# jquery, prevent enter on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the form a change event is being fired.

I need to disable this function key to <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I need to keep the event as change.

Is there a function to validate the field before sending the form? I will accept other suggestions.

```
$('input').change(function(){
   alert('check field');
});

$('form').submit(function(){
   submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$('input').change(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) return false;
    alert('check field');
});
```

Comment: but I want to submit the form, just do not want to enter the fire 2 simultaneous functions

Comment: did not work, it seems the 'change' does not capture the event

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a form validation plugin for jquery, for example the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).  You already have jQuery anyway and this plugin will solve the large majority of your validation problems automatically.